# Loading wordpress post into div using ajax and masonry javascript, but href isn't loading into div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I've seen a few issues with this before, but within a masonry script I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Result: the link opens an entirely new page, when what I'm trying to do is load the content into the div.

index.php code:

```
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="miniLoader"></div>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="miniLoader" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
      }?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

header.php code:

```
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      });
});
 </script>

 <?php wp_head(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".miniLoader").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr("href")
    $("#miniLoader").html("loading...");
    $("#miniLoader").load(post_link);
    return false;
 });

 });
```

As far as I know, the placement is in the loop and the script falls into place for where it should be. Or am I getting bad advice for placement and the 'rel'? I've heard about not using 'rel' anymore what with html5 and wordpress 3.5...

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

(please let me know if I'm missing pieces of the puzzle for this to make sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hansvedo

After much mucking about, here is how I've solved the script problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$("h1 a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#miniloader").html("loading...");
    $("#miniloader").load(post_link);
return false;
});

});
```

and the index alteration as follows:

```
<div id="miniloader" class="miniloader"></div>
```

I've been trying to implement your hint at only loading the #content, but to no avail. Looks like there isn't a 'content' ID, but I did try to implement one in the code below:

```
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <header class="entry-header">
 <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <div class="entry-meta">
 <?php toolbox_posted_on(); ?>
 </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
 </header><!-- .entry-header -->
 <div class="entry-content" id="content">
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'toolbox' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding event.preventDefault() to disable the normal link action:

```
$(".miniLoader").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

And the post_link variable appears to still need to be set:

```
var post_id = $(this).attr("href");
var post_link = 'your-api-file.php?id=' + post_id;
$("#miniLoader").html("loading...");
$("#miniLoader").load(post_link);
```

Oh and if you don't have an API file, jQuery can actually just load a whole WordPress page, but only display the content from the element that you want. In this case the AJAX load request will only grab and show what's in the #content element:

```
$('#miniLoader').load('/?p='+ post_id +' #content');
```

Comment: Thanks hansvedo! That seems to halt the loading of the new page with an entire refresh, however the content doesn't load into the miniLoader div. It just hangs with the "Loading..." output.

Comment: What is "post_link" referencing? Looks like you still need to create that variable: $("#miniLoader").load(post_link);

Comment: Ah. Looks like that should have been declared in ./ var post_link = $(this).attr("href") /. rather than ./ post_id /.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with me running this via MAMP, but the closest I can get to making this work is getting the div to show "Loading...", but the contents of the #content id from the script above still isn't working. Any chance you could tell me what the : /?p= means? I'm pretty new to PHP and still learning the ins and outs of wordpress as well, so maybe that's what I'm having trouble with... Thanks again @hansvedo !

Comment: Two parts: 1) /?p=123 is a quick way to access a WordPress page like: http://wordpress.org/news/?p=2525  You could also use a permalink, just anything to load a page. and 2) You'll want to make sure you actually have a DIV on that page with an ID of "content", otherwise update "#content" to an actual element on your page. Maybe post more sample code if that's not coming together.

Comment: I actually ended up solving the issue! Thanks to your help. I'll post the answer in a new 'answer' below.

Comment: awesome, glad you got it going